# Adding to a DataGridView Programmatically C# Winforms

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am adding to a datagridview with code. I have some data in lists and it adds to the datagridview just fine. However, I want to change the color of the font but I cannot get the color to work. Any ideas on how to change the color of the font for a row in datagridview.Here is the function:

```
public void LoadDGV()
{
    try
    {

        //load DGV
        dgvResults.Columns["Menu Item"].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        dgvResults.Rows.Add("Entrees");
        dgvResults.Columns["Menu Item"].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        //fill the datagrid view with values from Shop form
        for (int i = 0; i < lstQuantityEntrees.Count(); i++)
        {
            dgvResults.Rows.Add();
            dgvResults[0, i+1].Value = lstNameEntrees[i];
            dgvResults[1, i+1].Value = lstQuantityEntrees[i];
            dgvResults[2, i+1].Value = ((lstQuantityEntrees[i] * lstPriceEntrees[i]).ToString("C2"));
        }
        dgvResults.Columns["Menu Item"].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        dgvResults.Rows.Add("Drinks");
        dgvResults.Columns["Menu Item"].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message + ex.Message, "Program Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: It'd probably be easier and look better to use N different gridviews in a table layout panel, the headers being the dividers

Comment: I dont know what that means.

Comment: Put two DataGridView controls on the form, one above the other, one for drinks, one for entrees

Comment: If your saying use seperate datagridviews...I am trying to do it one with just a row before each subdivision.

Comment: I dont have room for two...I need to do it all in one

Comment: I know this can be done...

Comment: I just dont know why the first row doesnt show up.

Comment: Eh? Why do you think two 500px high datagridviews take up more room than one 1000px high one?

Comment: Any idea why the color doesnt change either?

Comment: I appreciate the advice but it kind of needs all be in one datagridview.

Comment: I will figure it out eventually. Just thought someone might point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you don't specify the exact row to put the data in so you will do something like this:
If you are using radish studio
1: Use Event SelectionChanged and write the encoding like
TextBox.Text =dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

The second problem is to specify the colors for each row, and this will be either by writing the following line of code in the previous event or by choosing an event (CellFormatting) and writing the following lines:
dataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(77, 148, 255);
dataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;

Comment: thanks....i got it figured out now